# Fourier transform of a spectrum

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, substitution, dirac-delta

I have the following definitions of Fourier transform FT with its inverse IFT for the complex function $h$ such that
$$
h(\omega)=\mathcal{F}\{h(t)\}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)e^{i\omega t}dt \\
h(t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{h(\omega)\} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}d\omega
$$
and the definition of the delta function as
$$
\delta(\omega+\omega^{\prime}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i(\omega+\omega^{\prime})t}dt.
$$
The spectrum of $h$ is hence defined as
$$
S_{hh}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\tau\,e^{i\omega\tau}\left<h^{\star}(t+\tau)h(t)\right>_{t=0} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega^{\prime}\left<h^{\star}(-\omega)h(\omega^{\prime})\right>.
$$
My question is: Using the definition of the delta function and the FT, IFT of $h$, how do I show the second equality in the preceding equation?

Comment: What do the angle brackets represent here?

Comment: It means expectation values. It should just carry over when the second equality sign, it doesn't affect the derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the IFT expressions for $h$ and $h^*$ into the spectrum integral to get
$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\iiint_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\omega \tau}\left\langle e^{i\omega''(t+\tau)}e^{-i\omega't}h^*(\omega'')h(\omega')\right\rangle_{t=0}d\omega''d\omega'd\tau
$$
We now pull the functions of time out of the expectation value (I assume this is OK) and set $t= 0$ to get
$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\iiint_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\omega \tau}e^{i\omega''\tau}\left\langle h^*(\omega'')h(\omega')\right\rangle d\omega''d\omega'd\tau = \frac{1}{2\pi}\iiint_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i(\omega+\omega'')\tau}}{2\pi}d\tau  \left\langle h^*(\omega'')h(\omega')\right\rangle d\omega'' d\omega'\\=\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(\omega + \omega'')  \left\langle h^*(\omega'')h(\omega')\right\rangle d\omega'' d\omega' = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left\langle h^*(-\omega)h(\omega')\right\rangle d\omega'
$$
A factor of $2\pi$ seems to have escaped somewhere. Might want to check normalization conventions for the Fourier transform.